# onclick .load() 2 variables

Tags: jquery, ajax

Using this script to send id to file.php which queries database and returns output in #DIV,

```
function recp(id + page) {

 $('#DIV').load('file.php?id=' + id + '& page=' + page);

}
```

works fine with just (id) but no luck with 2 variables. Checked on the appropriate sites without any result.

How would I also configure my `Onclick=recp('$id ...')`

Help much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a space in your query string. It should be:

```
$('#DIV').load('file.php?id=' + id + '&page=' + page);
```

It is much neater to pass an object as second [data] parameter:

```
$('#DIV').load('file.php', {id: id, page: page});
```

Comment: thank for the quick reply, how would I configure the onclick event?

Comment: @David - that depends on what you're trying to do.

Comment: onClick=recp('$id') echoing row id and page id $page

Comment: So onClick=recp('$id + $page')?

Comment: @David - `onClick="recp('$id', '$page')"` - unless you are concatenating $id and $page, in which case: `onClick="recp('$id' + '$page')"`